# Let discord bot interact with other bots

Tags: python, automation, discord, discord.py

I have a Python script for a Discord bot and I want it to send a message to another Bot and select the prompt option and then type in a message but I can't get the interaction done.

It just sends the message without triggering the interaction.

This is the code that I'm using to post a message in the channel:

```
        #Post in Test channel image descriptions
    channel = bot.get_channel(channel_id)
    for i in random_image_descriptions:
        await channel.send('/imagine ' + i)

    #Close bot
    await bot.close()
```

And this should be the result:

[image: Result]

Can someone help how I get the bot to post a prompt into the channel?

Answer (score 0):

**Bots cannot execute other bots' slash commands.** They can only listen to and react when human users invoke their own slash commands.

Comment: Is there a possible workaround?

Comment: No, slash commands are only designed for human interaction. And multiple bots may have an **imagine** command, so there would be confusion.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to invoke your bot's commands from other bots.
If you want to trigger a function on bot A from bot B, I suggest you use the `on_message` event on bot A to handle requests from bot B.
Example:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
REQUESTS_CHANNEL_ID = 100000000000000000000


intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True  # This is needed to use the on_message event
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)


async def foo():
    pass


@bot.event
async def on_message(message: discord.Message):
    if message.channel.id == REQUESTS_CHANNEL_ID:
        if message.content.startswith(f"$foo"):
            await foo()
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

This way, for bot B to request that the `foo` function of bot A be executed, it just needs to send a message starting with `$foo` in the channel `REQUESTS_CHANNELS`. It is important that this channel is private and only bots have access, thus preventing malicious users from having control over bot A.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you one thing in this case. Across all my searching on this I have not found this to be the case that it will interact with it, but you can set up a function using autopygui to interact that will work.
Simply picture the prompt field, setup the locate on screen using cv2, then when it selects, the paste in the /imagine which autofills and .hotkey() the enter button then paste in what you want to prompt and then .hotkey() the enter button again and you'll be autoprompting.

Hope that helps as far as a concept for working. I can tell you it works because i do it.

Pyautogui is excellent for doing this stuff on screen, but strictly as a bot for other people, it could still be implemented.
I'll show you my code that works, and i'm also working to improve to kind of give you an idea where its going.

```
def place_data_s_unique(where,info):
try:
    pag.click(where)
    pag.typewrite(info)
    time.sleep(2)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

def locate_pictures(picture):
try:
    # Load the target button image
    target_button = cv2.imread(picture,0)
    # Take a screenshot of the screen
    screenshot = pag.screenshot()
    screenshot = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(screenshot), cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    # Perform template matching
    result = cv2.matchTemplate(screenshot, target_button, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    # Define a threshold for matching
    threshold = 0.8
    # Get the location of matched buttons above the threshold
    locations = np.where(result >= threshold)
    x,y = 0,0
    height,width = target_button.shape
    for number in range(0,locations[0].size):
        if locations[0][number] > y:
            x = locations[1][number]+(width/2)
            y = locations[0][number]+(height/2)
    return x,y
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

def enter_prompt(temporary_folder,amount):
try:
    mid_prompt = []
    with open(f'{temporary_folder}/mid_prompt.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f: mid_prompt.append(line)
    mid_prompt = mid_prompt[0]
    discord_prompt = locate_pictures(f"{temporary_folder}discord_prompt.png")
    place_data_s_unique(discord_prompt,'/imagine')
    time.sleep(0.75)
    pag.hotkey('Enter')
    pag.typewrite(mid_prompt)
    time.sleep(0.75)
    pag.hotkey('Enter')
    time.sleep(1)
    pass
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```